# Form Validation using Jquery with numbers and letters

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, input

I am building a validation for testing to make sure that a correct part number has been entered.  Each part begins with MR in CAPS followed by a [SPACE] followed three numbers. e.g. ( MR 123 )

The problem is if i can not seem to figure out how to validate this using jquery.

The part number always begins with MR.

```
                var type = $("input#type").val();

                        // Check a that a tank type has been entered.
                        if( type.length < 5  && type.not().contain("MR")){

                                $("#error_upload").html("Please enter the tank number in a format MR XXX.");
                                $("#type").css({borderColor:'red'}).focus();                                    
                                $("name,#file").css({borderColor:'#ccc'});
                                return false;

                        }
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using regex.

```
if (type.match(/^MR\s[0-9]{3}$/){
...
}
```

Basically, it looks for MR, then a space (`\s`), then 3 numbers (`[0-9]{3}`). If anything else shows up, it will return false.

Comment: This will report as correct [if the inputted value is `abcMR 123`](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/QPhSS/). Update: You have edited before I posted. :)

Comment: I edited it 18 minutes ago? You posted this 14 minutes ago. But thanks :P

Comment: Obviously, I had not reloaded the page. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (/^MR \d{3}$/.test(subject)) {
    // Correct tank number format
} else {
    // Incorrect tank number format
}
```

This will ensure that the entered value is always only `MR` + `[SPACE]` + `3 digits` and only that.

Answer (score 1):

There are several routes you could go here.

1. One continue by writing your validation in this manner

   - You would want your code to probably look something like the following

     ```
     var type = $("input#type").val();

     // Check a that a tank type has been entered.
     if(!/^MR \d{3}$/.test(type)){

         $("#error_upload").html("Please enter the tank number in a format MR XXX.");
         $("#type").css({borderColor:'red'}).focus();                                    
         $("name,#file").css({borderColor:'#ccc'});
         return false;

     }
     ```
2. Integrate something like the above into jQuery Validate, since I'm assuming you'll need validation elsewhere
3. Simplify the entry by allowing only 3 digits and appending on `'MR ' + type`, since every one of these requires MR and a space, why ask the user to even enter it?

   ```
   var num = $("input#type").val()
   ,   type;

   // Check a that a tank type has been entered.
   if(!/^\d{3}$/.test(num)){

       $("#error_upload").html("Please enter the tank number with only digits.");
       $("#type").css({borderColor:'red'}).focus();                                    
       $("name,#file").css({borderColor:'#ccc'});
       return false;

   }
   else {
       type = 'MR ' + num;
   }
   ```
4. Combine step 2 and 3, which would result on having an input like this `<input type="text" class="required digits" maxlength="3" minlength="3" />`. This results in less complex data entry and not having to worry about simple validation logic. This is my favorite choice.
5. Use a input mask to prevent users from making any mistakes to begin with, but it is the most "intrusive".